# В sublime text 3 не работает emmet в sass-файлах

Tags: sass, sublime-text, sublime-text-3, emmet

Доброго времени суток. В sublime у меня уже подключен emmet и в html и в css он работает. Но в sass-файле - нет. Кто может сказать почему и как это исправить?Нужно дополнительно emmet для sass подключать или как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо поставить расширение SASS. После чего надо выбрать SASS в правом нижнем углу.

Answer (score 2):

Надо добавить поддержку SASS в настойках emmet:

Preferences -> Package Settings -> Emmet -> Settings-User

вставить строку

```
{
    "css_completions_scope": "source.css - meta.selector.css - meta.property-value.css, source.scss - meta.selector.scss - meta.property-value.scss, source.less - meta.selector.css - meta.property-value.css, source.sass - meta.selector.sass - meta.property-value.sass"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если в emmet комментарии оформлены как `*/text`, тогда плагин emmet не заработает. Нужно либо удалить эти комментарии, либо через двойной слеш `//text`